# How do Ant-Man and others change size without special suits?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-and-the-wasp

In the first *Ant-Man*, Hank Pym explained that the special suit and helmet were required to contain the Pym particles in order to vary the person's size. But in *Ant-Man and the Wasp*, people change the size of cars and buildings without the suit. How is this possible? There is also a scene where Scott becomes small/big without helmet. Did I miss an explanation from movie?

Comment: I have an feeling it's unfortunately going be [the rule of cool](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool). Same reason why sometimes their weight shrinks with them and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Clearly the suit isn't technically needed to contain the Pym particles, since even in the first movie they were shrinking and growing stuff that wasn't contained in something. Like, say, the ant that got embiggened, or the Thomas the Tank Engine toy, or the device that Scott stole from the Avengers and shrank.

Comment: Compared to the first movie, the cars and building seem easy: The cars act the same way as big suits, which is why people in the cars are safe - they're evenly surrounded by Pym particles. And they only ever shrank one building, which must have been specifically prepared, if only to keep everything in place when shrunk. - I don't remember a scene where Scott changes size without helmet though, that would definitely break the suit rule.. when was that?

Comment: @AlexRuyven When Scott and Hope infiltrate Cassie's school to retrieve the old suit, Scott accidentally shrinks to child size without wearing his helmet. He also embiggens in a broom closet or something and I don't believe he has a helmet there either.

Comment: Ahh right, I remember now. Then we can only make assumptions, like maybe the full suit with helmet minimizes the risk of catastrophic failure and he just got lucky.. i.e. rule of cool.

Answer (score 3):

In the first movie, Darren Cross shrinks a sheep which is in a special protective container, which acted as big suit. We can assume that Hank specially prepared the building and cars to work in a similar fashion.